# Save complex object during flask session

Tags: python3, user, session, flask

I need advice.
My flask application has no database.
I have a custom authorization system.
I connect to the API service and during the user session, I make requests to it.
Tell me where to save the connector complex object) to the service so that it is different for each user.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a solution.
In the class where the routes are collected, I allocated a dist class object.
Keys are hashes of a piece of unique data for each user, and values are connector objects.
I put the keys in a flask session and every time I need it, I get a connector from this dict.
Thanks to all.